# Creating a new word document with custom margin

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to create a new word document with a custom page margin set up. I have written this code but it seems to break down at the WITH statements. Not quite sure why is this happening however.

```
 Sub test()

    Dim docCreate As Document

    Set docCreate = Documents.Add

    With docCreate.PageSetup
        .TopMargin = WordApp.InchesToPoints(0.6)
        .BottomMargin = WordApp.InchesToPoints(0.6)
        .LeftMargin = WordApp.InchesToPoints(0.6)
        .RightMargin = WordApp.InchesToPoints(0.6)
    End With

    docCreate.Range.Paste

End Sub
```

Comment: `seems to break down at the WITH statements` is not very specific. What happens? Any error messages?

Comment: You should tell us on which line it breaks, but I bet my hat it breaks where you call the undeclared `WordApp`.

Comment: Which is something you would find out immediately if you added `Option Explicit` at the top of each code module, to force every variable used to be explicitly declared, and not just assumed to be a `Variant`...

Comment: @OlleSjögren has just given you one of the most important programming tips you will ever receive. Learn to use the Option Explicit, it will be harder the first day but you will avoid sooo many issues.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
Sub test2()

    Dim docCreate As Document

    Set docCreate = Documents.Add

    With docCreate.PageSetup
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.6)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.6)
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.6)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.6)
    End With

    docCreate.Range.Paste


End Sub
```

The problem is that `WordApp` is not defined, it probably comes from where you copied-pasted this snippet. Either you define it (`Set wordApp = Application` if you want the current one or `Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")` if you want a new one), or you simply use the object `Application` as I did above (but you assume, like this, that you're working on the currently running Word app).